# iOS horizontal scrollable tab bar in Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, tabbar

Recently, I find a iPhone app using horizontal scrollable tab bar and the item in the tab bar can be add or remove in the bar. I want to know which ui framework is using for this feature. Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can do it using UICollection view with horizontal layout basically

Comment: Do you know any github project is using this features?

Comment: Sorry, one more thing I want to know is the UICollection view support the "Arrow" show at the end of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you can implement this using UIPageViewController. Thing is that using it, it's hard to catch how far have you scrolled the page so far to position "underline" correctly.

The best solution I see is to use UIScrollView and position everything yourself. There was a WWDC presentation how to use UIScrollView to "swipe" through images (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/104/). You will find step by step guide how to get the result you need.